# Matching date columns with unequal length in R

Tags: r, matching

I have data in the following format with 3 date columns

```
X <- c(24/02/2016, 25/02/2016, 26/02/2016, 29/02/2016, 01/03/2016, 02/03/2016,  03/03/2016, 04/03/2016, 07/03/2016, 08/03/2016, 09/03/2016, 10/03/2016, 11/03/2016, 14/03/2016, 15/03/2016)
Y <- c(26/08/2014, 10/09/2014,24/09/2014, 09/10/2014, 24/02/2016, 09/03/2016, 24/03/2016, 11/04/2016, 26/04/2016)
Z <- c(15/08/2014,  29/08/2014, 15/09/2014, 30/09/2014, 12/02/2016, 29/02/2016, 15/03/2016, 31/03/2016, 15/04/2016)
```

the output i want is like below

```
X                     Output
24/02/2016          12/02/2016
25/02/2016             NA
26/02/2016             NA
29/02/2016             NA
01/03/2016             NA
02/03/2016             NA
03/03/2016             NA
04/03/2016             NA
07/03/2016             NA
08/03/2016             NA
09/03/2016         29/02/2016
10/03/2016             NA
11/03/2016             NA
14/03/2016             NA
15/03/2016             NA
```

Basically the problem is wherever there is a match between X and Y, i need Z corresponding to X in a new column.
I am not really good with R so not able to figure out how to come up with a solution. Any ideas ?

Comment: This question should be asked at Stack Overflow

Comment: How does Z correspond to X? I can't figure it out from your example

Comment: Maybe simply `Z[match(X,Y)]`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in base R using `match`, but I find it cleaner to use the `dplyr` package and `left_join`.

```
library(dplyr)

# make a data frame with X as a column
X.df <- data.frame(X = c("24/02/2016", "25/02/2016", "26/02/2016", "29/02/2016", "01/03/2016", "02/03/2016", "03/03/2016", "04/03/2016", "07/03/2016", "08/03/2016", "09/03/2016", "10/03/2016", "11/03/2016", "14/03/2016", "15/03/2016"), stringsAsFactors = F)

# make a data frame with Y and Z as columns
YZ.df <- data.frame(Y = c("26/08/2014", "10/09/2014", "24/09/2014", "09/10/2014", "24/02/2016", "09/03/2016", "24/03/2016", "11/04/2016", "26/04/2016"), Z = c("15/08/2014", "29/08/2014", "15/09/2014", "30/09/2014", "12/02/2016", "29/02/2016", "15/03/2016", "31/03/2016", "15/04/2016"), stringsAsFactors = F)

# do a left join, specifying variables X and Y
left_join(X.df, YZ.df, by = c("X" = "Y"))
```

Note that the above will create duplicate rows for X if there is more than one corresponding Z value for a Y value that matches an X value.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is the `data.table` version complementing [gatsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47201547/3817004):

```
library(data.table)
data.table(Y, Z)[data.table(X), on = .(Y == X), .(X, Z)]
```

> ```
>              X          Z
>  1: 24/02/2016 12/02/2016
>  2: 25/02/2016         NA
>  3: 26/02/2016         NA
>  4: 29/02/2016         NA
>  5: 01/03/2016         NA
>  6: 02/03/2016         NA
>  7: 03/03/2016         NA
>  8: 04/03/2016         NA
>  9: 07/03/2016         NA
> 10: 08/03/2016         NA
> 11: 09/03/2016 29/02/2016
> 12: 10/03/2016         NA
> 13: 11/03/2016         NA
> 14: 14/03/2016         NA
> 15: 15/03/2016         NA
> ```

#### Data

```
Z <- c("15/08/2014", "29/08/2014", "15/09/2014", "30/09/2014", "12/02/2016", "29/02/2016", "15/03/2016", "31/03/2016", "15/04/2016")
Y <- c("26/08/2014", "10/09/2014", "24/09/2014", "09/10/2014", "24/02/2016", "09/03/2016", "24/03/2016", "11/04/2016", "26/04/2016")
X <- c("24/02/2016", "25/02/2016", "26/02/2016", "29/02/2016", "01/03/2016", "02/03/2016", "03/03/2016", "04/03/2016", "07/03/2016", "08/03/2016", "09/03/2016", "10/03/2016", "11/03/2016", "14/03/2016", "15/03/2016")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using match

```
# Construct data
Z = c("15/08/2014", "29/08/2014", "15/09/2014", "30/09/2014", "12/02/2016", "29/02/2016", "15/03/2016", "31/03/2016", "15/04/2016")
Y = c("26/08/2014", "10/09/2014", "24/09/2014", "09/10/2014", "24/02/2016", "09/03/2016", "24/03/2016", "11/04/2016", "26/04/2016")
df <- data.frame(X = c("24/02/2016", "25/02/2016", "26/02/2016", "29/02/2016", "01/03/2016", "02/03/2016", "03/03/2016", "04/03/2016", "07/03/2016", "08/03/2016", "09/03/2016", "10/03/2016", "11/03/2016", "14/03/2016", "15/03/2016"), stringsAsFactors = F)

# Match df$X to Y and return that index of Z
df$Output<-Z[match(df$X,Y)]
```

Output

```
> df

            X     Output
1  24/02/2016 12/02/2016
2  25/02/2016       <NA>
3  26/02/2016       <NA>
4  29/02/2016       <NA>
5  01/03/2016       <NA>
6  02/03/2016       <NA>
7  03/03/2016       <NA>
8  04/03/2016       <NA>
9  07/03/2016       <NA>
10 08/03/2016       <NA>
11 09/03/2016 29/02/2016
12 10/03/2016       <NA>
13 11/03/2016       <NA>
14 14/03/2016       <NA>
15 15/03/2016       <NA>
```

Comment: What if my Z variable is not a date but a numeric variable ? will the same logic apply ?

Comment: It should, if Z and Y are vectors of unique numbers. It should be easy enough to test